# Left text direction using tableGrob gridExtra

Tags: r, gridextra, gtable

I am trying to format a table using `gridExtra` package and I use the function `str_wrap` to Wrap the Strings.

```
df=data.frame(name=c("ABC","XYZ","DEF"),
              description=c(rep(str_wrap("This is an example for text wrap using grid.draw in package gridExtra ", width = 60),3))
tg <- tableGrob(df)
grid.draw(tg)
```

[image]

now the new string is in the center of the cell .

Is there any way to make the new line start also from the left like the First line ?

Comment: I think this is probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34962951/gridextra-align-text-to-right . For your case change the theme in [Baptiste's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34962951/gridextra-align-text-to-right#34973212) to `core = list(fg_params=list(hjust=0, x=0.01))`